# How to migrate a question to ELL

Tags: support, migration

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/155322/15004) has been put on hold as being too basic and thus off-topic.

I would like to vote for this question to be migrated to ELL rather than deleted, but the only three options I see in "flag" are:

- it is spam
- it is offensive, abusive, or hate speech
- other (needs ♦ moderator attention)

I've used the last option, but I seem to remember there used to be an option for migrating to ELL. Is this option gone?

---

**Update**

I don't think this migration is necessary any longer. I've found an answer to this question [on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/17272/4559).

Comment: There has never been an option to migrate to ELL.

Comment: @MattЭллен, is it not possible? BTW, my choice of wording "the latter" vs "the last one" was [intentional](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/11914/15004) :)

Comment: OK, feel free to roll back my edit. Please see [this question](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4564/couldnt-select-proper-close-question-reason) for information on how to request a question be migrated. Essentially: what you have done is our only option.

Comment: @MattЭллен,thanks. I'm happy with the edit. It tells me some people really mind.

Comment: I'm not privy to TPTB reasoning here, but it seems likely to me they don't provide the option because ELL is still in beta mode.

Comment: Does the duplicate really handle this case as well? The OP is asking about an already closed question (which needs to be reopened first, which a single user can't do).